# mouseover with javascript

Tags: mouseover

I am having a really hard time getting the mouseover to work in javascript with my navigation bar.  I have made some changes but still not working.

```
  <div class="left_side">  
   <ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="main2.html">Home</a></li>
   <td
    onmouseover="document.getElementById(
    'b1')src.'button1over.png'"
    onmouseout="document.getElementById(
    'b1')src.'button1up.png'" 
      <li><a href="#">Our Team</a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="faculty.html">Faculty</a>
     <li><a href="fellows.html">Fellows</a>
     </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`b1')src.'button1over` .. should be `b1').src='button1over`

Make sure to correct the `onmouseout` event as well..